# How can I add state to a lexer in Racket?

Tags: racket, lexer

I am trying to write a lexer for the sed language in Racket (ex. "s/find/replace/"). One problem I have been encountering is dealing with the fact that a lot of the tokens have no definitive form and can change. For example, I can write the above example as "ssfindsreplaces", where the letter 's' is used instead of '/'.

I've started writing a lexer such as,

```
(define sed-lexer
  (lexer-srcloc
   ["\n" (token 'NEWLINE lexeme)]
   ["/" (token 'DIVIDER lexeme]
   [(:or "s" "y" "d" "p") (token 'CMD lexeme)]
   [(:* (complement "/") (token 'LITERAL lexeme)]))
```

but this fails on multiple levels:

- The command can only come at the beginning (in this simplified example). After a command has been read I want to ignore the command case until a newline.
- The DIVIDER token can't be set always as a slash.

I can imagine a solution to this problem could be adding states to this lexer. So for example, the lexer starts in a 'start' state where it looks for a command, then it goes to the 'divider1' state, looking for what will be the divider character. Such a feature seems to exist here http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/.  What would be the best way to go about solving this problem given the tools in the Racket ecosystem?

Comment: Which lexer are you using? https://github.com/racket/racket/wiki/language-development-toolchain#lexers-and-parsers

Comment: I was trying to get it work with the lexer at "br-parser-tools/lex" but I'd be open for a solution with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lexer is simply a function that consumes an input port and returns a token. If `(br-)parser-tools/lex` is not enough for you, you can write it yourself (it should not be difficult).

In theory, finite state machine and regular expression are equally expressive, so I think you can in fact use `parser-tools/lex` to accomplish what you want. It will just look really tedious due to how you need to split cases over all possible "divider"s (because pure regular expression doesn't have the backreference ability). I think that pygments that you mentioned will have a similar problem.

Another possibility is to use something more powerful than regular expression. As sed grammar is pretty simple, you can even parse it right away without lexing first. Here's a crappy version I wrote quickly using `megaparsack`, a parser combinator library

```
#lang racket

(require megaparsack megaparsack/text
         data/monad data/applicative)

(struct substitution (search replace flags) #:transparent)

(define substitution/p (do (char/p #\s)
                           [divider <- any-char/p]
                           [search <- (many/p (char-not/p divider))]
                           (char/p divider)
                           [replace <- (many/p (char-not/p divider))]
                           (char/p divider)
                           [flags <- (many/p (char-in/p "gIp"))]
                           (pure (substitution search replace flags))))

(define dummy-command/p (string/p "dummy-command"))

(define line/p (or/p substitution/p
                     dummy-command/p))

(define program/p (do [result <- (many/p line/p #:sep (char/p #\newline))]
                      eof/p
                      (pure result)))

(pretty-print
 (parse-result!
  (parse-string program/p
                "s/hello/world/\ndummy-command\ns|search|replace|gp")))

#|

Result:

(list
 (substitution '(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o) '(#\w #\o #\r #\l #\d) '())
 "dummy-command"
 (substitution
  '(#\s #\e #\a #\r #\c #\h)
  '(#\r #\e #\p #\l #\a #\c #\e)
  '(#\g #\p)))

|#
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. It's great to see a solutions to this problem that I didn't know about.